# $L^{p}$ convergence and convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I found this as a part of the proof that I was trying to accomplish. More specifically it says,

If $X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in probability i.e., $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and $\mid X_{n}\mid \le Y$ $ \:\forall n\ $ and $\Bbb{E}[Y^{p}] < \infty$ then
$$X_n \xrightarrow{L^p}X$$

after some calculations I came to this inequality,
$$\mathbb{E}[\mid X_n-X\mid^p] < \epsilon^p+2^p\Bbb{E}[Y^p\Bbb{I}_{A_n}] \:\:\: \epsilon \ge0$$ , where $A_n :=\{\mid X_n-X\mid > \epsilon\}$

My idea is to show $\Bbb{E}[Y^p\Bbb{I}_{A_n}] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ , and then let , $\epsilon$ go small to prove the result. But I'm stuck at the last line i.e., I am unable to show, $\Bbb{E}[Y^p\Bbb{I}_{A_n}] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Can anyone help me prove this statement?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have no Idea on how to approach this

Comment: Folks can actually ask homework question, but they *need to contribute context*, so no need for the defensive **bold face**.  Homework or not, this site is not a "do this for me" site.  You ask: "Can anyone help me prove this statement?"  which clearly suggests "do this for me".  Why is this question important to you? If you don't know much about measure theory, then maybe you won't understand answers?  Why don't you specify what you are looking for in an answer?

Comment: If $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, then it converges along some subsequence to $X$ almost surely. Then by dominated convergence $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L_p$ along such subsequence. Now, If you take any subsequence of $X_n$, you obtain a sub subsequence that converges to $X$ in $L_p$. From this one may conclude that indeed, $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L_p$.

Comment: Oliver, the OP made clear they don't know much about $L_p$ spaces....

Comment: @amWhy I clearly mentioned what I am looking for, I am not looking for a all-new solution from scratch but someone who can complete my proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lebesgue majorized convergence theorem you will get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega} |X_n -X |^p dP =\int_{\Omega} \lim_{n\to\infty}|X_n -X |^p dP =0$$
bu this means that $||X-X_n ||_{L^p} \to 0.$

Comment: can you always interchange $\lim$ and $\int$. And By Lebesgue majorized convergence theorem do you mean Dominated Convergence theorem?

Comment: That's another name for the (Lebesgue's) Dominated Convergence Theorem. (I think more typical in some of European languages.) You cannot always switch the order the limit and the integral, but the Dominated Convergence Theorem gives sufficient conditions to do so.

Comment: @zxmkn How can one interchange the $\lim$ and $\int$ signs? Under what conditions on DCT one can do so. All DCT says is
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} |X_n|^p dP = \int_{\Omega} |X|^p dP
$$

Comment: In the usual formulations of Lebesgue's theorem, a.s.-convergence is required. This can be salvaged with the sub-sub-sequence argument mentioned in a comment to the question by Oliver Díaz.

Answer (score 0):

Let, $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ denote the region of the sample space where $|X_n - X| > \epsilon$. Since, $X_n \xrightarrow{\operatorname{P}} X$, we have $P(\Omega_{\epsilon}) \rightarrow 0$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. In other words, the measure of $\Omega_{\epsilon}$ approaches $0$. So,
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[Y^p \mathbb{I}_{A_n}] &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{|X_n -  X| >\epsilon} Y^p dP \\
                                 &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega_{\epsilon}} Y^p dP \\
                                 &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
since, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\Omega_{\epsilon}) = 0$